# for文のLOOPが重複してしまいます。

Tags: python, python3

以下のような、月別のテスト結果（ABC評価）があった際に、「平均」と各クラスの評価を結合させたいと考えております。
[image: 元のデータ]

[image: 評価を結合]

loopを用いて各要素だけを結合したいのですが、計算結果が重複してしまいます。

```
df = pd.read_excel("~/テスト.xlsx")
df1 = df['平均']
df2 = df.iloc[1:,2:]#1組から5組まで

df3 = []
for i in df1:
    for index , j in df2.iterrows():
        df3.append(list(i+j))
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

applyを使えば列ごとに連結処理を行えます。

```py
df4 = df.iloc[:,2:].apply(df['平均'].str.cat)
df4 = pd.concat([df['時期'], df4], axis=1)
```

これで次のようなデータフレームが得られます(4組以降、2020-04-01以降は省略)。

```
          時期  1組  2組  3組
0 2020-01-01  AB  AC  AA
1 2020-02-01  AA  AC  AC
2 2020-03-01  CC  CB  CA
```

Comment: こちらご回答ありがとうございます。大変助かります。
applyで解決できるんですね。
applyの使い方についてこれまで触れてこなかったので勉強いたします。

Answer (score 1):

以下は [pandas.DataFrame.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) を使用する方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({
  '時期': ['2020/1/1', '2020/2/1', '2020/3/1', '2020/4/1', '2020/5/1', '2020/6/1',
           '2020/7/1', '2020/8/1', '2020/9/1', '2020/10/1', '2020/11/1', '2020/12/1'],
  '平均': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
   '1組': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
   '2組': ['C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
   '3組': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
   '4組': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
   '5組': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C'],
})

dfx = df.agg(
  lambda x: x if x.name in ('時期', '平均') else df['平均'] + x)

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(dfx)

=>
          時期  平均 1組 2組  3組 4組 5組
0    2020/1/1    A  AB  AC  AA  AA  AB
1    2020/2/1    A  AA  AC  AC  AC  AB
2    2020/3/1    C  CC  CB  CA  CA  CB
3    2020/4/1    C  CA  CA  CC  CA  CA
4    2020/5/1    B  BB  BC  BC  BC  BC
5    2020/6/1    B  BA  BA  BB  BA  BA
6    2020/7/1    B  BA  BB  BA  BB  BB
7    2020/8/1    B  BC  BC  BC  BA  BA
8    2020/9/1    A  AC  AA  AA  AC  AC
9   2020/10/1    C  CC  CB  CB  CA  CA
10  2020/11/1    A  AB  AB  AC  AB  AC
11  2020/12/1    B  BB  BA  BA  BC  BC
```